# How to decrypt message that's encrypted in AES-GCM-256?

Tags: encryption, rust

I need to make a client-server connection from node.js/javascript server to a client written in Rust. The message had to be encrypted with AES-GCM-256. While in Rust (version 1.67.0) I use [aes-gcm crate](https://docs.rs/aes-gcm/latest/aes_gcm/index.html).

The Rust code below throws an error: `aead::Error`. What's wrong with the `cipher.decrypt()` here ?

I'm sure that the node.js implementation is correct. I think that the `key` variable in Rust code should be the same key from the node.js (`12341234123412341234123412341234`)

**Implementation in Node.js / sender side**

```
const crypto = require('crypto')
const aes256gcm = (key) => {

    const encrypt = (str) => {
        const iv = new crypto.randomBytes(12);
        const ivString = iv.toString("base64")
        const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, iv);
        let enc1 = cipher.update(str, 'utf8');
        let enc2 = cipher.final();
        let result = Buffer.concat([enc1, enc2, iv, cipher.getAuthTag()]).toString("base64");
        return { result, iv: ivString }
    };

    const decrypt = (enc) => {
        enc = Buffer.from(enc, "base64");
        const iv = enc.slice(enc.length - 28, enc.length - 16);
        const tag = enc.slice(enc.length - 16);
        enc = enc.slice(0, enc.length - 28);
        const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, iv);
        decipher.setAuthTag(tag);
        let str = decipher.update(enc, null, 'utf8');
        str += decipher.final('utf8');
        return str;
    };

    return {
        encrypt,
        decrypt,
    };
};

const cipher = aes256gcm("12341234123412341234123412341234"); // just a test key must be 32
const ct = cipher.encrypt('Hello world!!!');
console.log("encrypted message: ", ct.result)
console.log("iv / nonce       : ", ct.iv)

const pt = cipher.decrypt(ct.result);
console.log("decrypted message: ", pt); // this works flawlessly!
```

**Encryption Result by Node.js**

```
encrypted message:  Zf5aB0bbVGGX3k9Yt6x+9daxCGZO0MmwYW8VUsOY4j3gNYXP47hvfGgd
iv / nonce       :  fvXWsQhmTtDJsGFv
decrypted message:  Hello world!!!
```

**The decryption part (Rust) / Receiver Side**

```
use aes_gcm::{
    aead::{Aead, KeyInit, OsRng},
    Aes256Gcm, Nonce,
};
use base64::{engine::general_purpose, Engine as _};

fn main() {

    // master key from sender  
    let master = "12341234123412341234123412341234".as_bytes();
    let cipher = Aes256Gcm::new_from_slice(master).unwrap();

    // nonce / iv from sender
    let nonce_str_base64 = "fvXWsQhmTtDJsGFv";
    let nonce_str: Vec<u8> = general_purpose::STANDARD.decode(nonce_str_base64).unwrap();
    let nonce = Nonce::from_slice(&nonce_str); // 96-bits; unique per message

    // encrypted text from sender
    let ciphertext_base64 = "Zf5aB0bbVGGX3k9Yt6x+9daxCGZO0MmwYW8VUsOY4j3gNYXP47hvfGgd";
    let ciphertext = general_purpose::STANDARD.decode(ciphertext_base64).unwrap();

    // gets aead::Error here
    match cipher.decrypt(nonce, ciphertext.as_slice()) {
        Ok(decrypted) => {
            let result = String::from_utf8(decrypted).unwrap();
            println!("result: {}", result);
        }
        Err(err) => print!("{}", err), <--- prints error: aead::Error
    };
}
```

Comment: what's wrong with my question ?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your question, I think. Looks like a case of somebody waking up from the wrong foot. (A question though: Any confidence that the JS code is correct? Also, I think you're lacking a `let ciphertext = general_purpose::STANDARD.decode(ciphertext).unwrap();` on line 19, but that doesn't make the error go away.)

Comment: You're right! since the decoded text is in base64 I should decode it too. I'm pretty sure that the sender side is correct (`payload + iv + postfix tag`). I'll check the AES-256-GCM documentation again to make sure

Comment: I edited my code to add decode function to ciphertext but the error still there.

Comment: I made it work ! it turns of that this Rust implementation of the AES-256-GCM de-cryptor (`cipher.decrypt()`) only accepts `payload + postfix tag`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AES-256-GCM consists of three parts:

1. `payload` or ciphered text,
2. `iv` or nonce, a unique random number that generated once
3. and the `tag` that is part of the authentication that ensures the encrypted message has not been altered

The [aes_gcm](https://docs.rs/aes-gcm/latest/aes_gcm/index.html) crate uses `payload` + `tag` for decryption. So the solution is to remove the `iv` part from the result message. I just change the sender side (Node.js) from this:

```
let result = Buffer.concat([enc1, enc2, iv, cipher.getAuthTag()]).toString("base64");
```

to this:

```
let result = Buffer.concat([enc1, enc2, cipher.getAuthTag()]).toString("base64");
```

the nonce/iv part is supplied to `cipher.decrypt` through function parameter